# ExceptionInInitializerError, AccessControlException , Unknown publishers Security warning,

Tags: java, japplet, jarsigner, jar-signing, signed-applet

i can't understand where problem lies to run applet in browser when deploy my project 
accordind to

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html

*jar manifest code*

```
Permissions: all-permisisons
Application-Name:------------
```

Butt still error

is problem to signing jar of my project?
3rd party jar files also use in my project e.g. jna , jvlc .Is need to be signing these jar?
when sign to jar fileNotFoundException in cmd for keystore.jks and .crt file

sign for jar use cmd
    jarsigner  path\abc.jar aliase

hepl me i off struck a few day in this problem.

Comment: Please don't treat the title of your question and the contents as one continuous block of text. Please clearly state your error messages within your question and create a new title that summarises your problem (rather than just being a dump of error messages).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unknown publishers applet browser, Signing jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406336/unknown-publishers-applet-browser-signing-jar)