# Unknown publishers applet browser, Signing jar

Tags: java, applet, japplet, jarsigner, jar-signing

i can't understand where problem lies to run applet in browser when deploy my project accordind to

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html

http://www.coderanch.com/t/258307/Applets/java/Signing-JAR-certificate

jar manifest code

```
Permissions: all-permisisons
Application-Name:------------
```

Butt still error in browser

Unknown publishers Security warning 
ExceptionInInitializerError 
AccessControlException

is problem to signing jar of my project?
i use 3rd party jar files in my project e.g. jna , vlcj .Is need to be signing these jar? when sign to jar fileNotFoundException in cmd for keystore.jks and .crt file

sign for jar use cmd

```
c:\<jdk-path>\bin>jarsigner path\abc.jar alias-name
```

display on cmd

```
jar signed.
Warning:
No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a times
tamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's
expiration date (4751-12-22) or after any future revocation date.
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused if updates were made with JDK Java/Oracle 1.7 u51. This JDK is NOT identical to the previous one.

You can install a previous version of the JDK BEFORE u51 (7u45 for exemple), or install JDK 6.

Then when you re-compile, you won't see the error.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695520/tsa-or-tsacert-timestamp-for-applet-jar-self-signed/21886019#21886019