# dreamweaver does create key sign for Android apps?

Tags: android, apk, dreamweaver

I created some web pages with html css and jquery, and I want to convert it to Android apps.

so I download android SDK and using Adobe dreamweaver 5.5 to create my apk file.

it was created and i installed on my phone without any problem. but when I want to upload my apk file to android stores I have a message that: program should not be on debug sign.

How can I remove debug sign or create a my own sign?

Comment: You should try this: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#google-play-app-signing

Answer (score 1):

You just have to create the **key** with `keytool` using the `command line` (in windows : **cmd.exe**)

[Here](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) is the guide how to do it (scroll down to "1. Obtain a suitable private key")

Comment: thanks for your reply. but in that note said i must use android studio to create my sign key. does any way to do this with dreamweaver ? i don't have android studio and i don't know how to install or use

Comment: @SRR the second doc is about signing android app's only . your problem must solve using `keytool` using `cmd` i said above

Comment: I finally got a key. now how can i sign my app with this key ?

Comment: @SRR try this : https://www.nalashaa.com/build-sign-zipalign-generated-apk-existing-key-store-file/

Comment: @SRR another topic in stackoverflow . pls read here  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930331/how-to-sign-an-already-compiled-apk

Comment: thanks again for your reply. I signed my app with my key as that command said. but at the end of command line i got this warning : No -tsa or -tsacart is provided and this jar is not timestamp...  . what does it mean ?

Comment: @SRR , check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695520/tsa-or-tsacert-timestamp-for-applet-jar-self-signed

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you are signing. Command line with Keytool

or Using Android studio. both ways are easy

For android studio I recommend reading [here](http://www.androiddocs.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

For the Keytool method its

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```